# AWS policy how to access to IP or ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to create AWS policy giving access to some IPs addresses **OR** Lambda for Elasticsearch service.

So, that have access to ES from IPs and that Lambda have access to.

This no working for me:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:xxx:domain/xxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "xxx",
            "xxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:xxx:domain/xxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:xxx:function:xxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for help.